# How to list all video file types - with their full path - present in the root of different drives in Windows?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

Say there are e.g. .mp4 and .mkv files at the root of several drives (D: E: F:), mixed with other non-video files.

I would like to get a list of only video file types, and only at the root, with their full path:

- D:\Cirque Du Soleil Corteo.mkv
- D:\Zina - Carla Chamoun.mp4
- E:\strange-cat-door-surprise_1.mp4
- F:\Geometric illusions 07.mkv

etc.

I have tried to combine:

```
for %%A in (*.mp4 *.mkv) do echo %%~dpnxA >> Dir.txt
```

which doesn't provide the full path, and obviously does it for only the current drive, with:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b /a-d %%p') do @echo %%~dpnxA
```

which does give the full path but doesn't seem to like *.mp4 *.mkv in the dir command; and tried

```
for /D %%p in (D: E: F:) do
```

to go through the different drives. Unsuccessfully thus far...

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do that with one line, using a single command:

[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)

```
%__AppDir__%where.exe D:\;E:\;F:\:*.mkv D:\;E:\;F:\:*.mp4 2>NUL >Dir.txt
```

[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```
@%__AppDir__%where.exe D:\;E:\;F:\:*.mkv D:\;E:\;F:\:*.mp4 2>NUL >Dir.txt
```

Comment: Don't you have to append the `\ `to each drive to specify its root? And I think you have to provide the location prefix also for the second pattern `*.mp4`...

Comment: @aschipfl, unless different operating systems change their behavior, no it is not necessary to use a backslash the `D:;E:;F::` syntax should work fine, except if the drive is the system drive. However, your nudge has reminded me of a more robust methodology, which also allows for the system drive to be one of the root drives. Technically, therefore, I have implemented both of your suggestions and updated my entire post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This command gives you all files with their full path, from the current directory:

```
forfiles /M *.mp4 /C "cmd /C echo @path"
forfiles /M *.mkv /C "cmd /C echo @path"
```

For your information: it's not possible to combine both extensions in the `/M` section of the `forfiles` command (but you might use an `if`-clause in the `/C` section), this can be done as follows (example provided by Compo):

```
... /C "Cmd /C If @Ext==0x22mp40x22 0x28Echo @Path0x29 Else If @Ext==0x22mkv0x22 Echo @Path"
```

You might need `cd /D` (mind the `/D` switch) to do this in the mentioned drives, something like:

```
cd /D D:\
cd \
forfiles /M *.mp4 ...
forfiles /M *.mkv ...
cd /D E:\
cd \
forfiles /M *.mp4 ...
forfiles /M *.mkv ...
cd /D F:\
cd \
forfiles /M *.mp4 ...
forfiles /M *.mkv ...
```

The `cd \` is to make sure you go to the root of the drive.

Comment: Based upon your statement, "it's not possible to combine both extensions in one `forfiles` command", can you explain what this does? `@%__AppDir__%forfiles.exe /P E: /C "Cmd /C If @Ext==0x22mp40x22 0x28Echo @Path0x29 Else If @Ext==0x22mkv0x22 Echo @Path"`. I think what you meant to say was that you cannot provide multiple searchmasks for the `/M` option.

Comment: @Compo: that's indeed what I meant.

Comment: Can you please delete your first comment.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that my comment above stipulated a drive without having to navigate to it, so it may be worth offering a single solution using a standard `for` loop with the `forfiles` example above, e.g. `@For %%G In (D E F) Do @%__AppDir__%forfiles.exe /P %%G: /C "Cmd /C If @Ext==0x22mp40x22 0x28Echo @Path0x29 Else If @Ext==0x22mkv0x22 Echo @Path"`